# React state not changing on first select input change

Tags: reactjs

I am attempting to sort and display information using select element option changes.

The data however does not change until I have changed both select value three times.

What is the reasoning why state won't change on first change? I was wondering if I am required to use a useEffect?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

PS - I have attempted to use useEffect and to listen and rerun on sortDirection and filterBy state changes

My current code:

```js
const Home = () => {
  const [phoneData, setPhoneData] = useState([
    { name: "Samsung", ppm: 50, upfront: 45 },
    { name: "Iphone", ppm: 60, upfront: 100 },
    { name: "Nokia", ppm: 40, upfront: 20 },
  ]);
  const [filteringBy, setFilteringBy] = useState("");
  const [sortDirection, setSortDirection] = useState("");


// sets sortDirection state to either ASC or DESC
  const handleDirectionFilter = (val) => {
    if (val === sortDirection) return;
    console.log(val);
    setSortDirection(val);
    sortPhoneData();
  };

// sets filterBy state to either ppm or upfront
  const handleFilterType = (val) => {
    if (val === filteringBy) return;
    console.log(val);
    setFilteringBy(val);
    sortPhoneData();
  };

// This function should sort data on first call hover takes many calls
  const sortPhoneData = () => {
    let newData;
    filteringBy === "ppm" && sortDirection === "ASC"
      ? (newData = phoneData.sort((a, b) => a.ppm - b.ppm))
      : (newData = phoneData.sort((a, b) => a.ppm + b.ppm));

    filteringBy === "upfront" && sortDirection === "ASC"
      ? (newData = phoneData.sort((a, b) => a.ppm - b.ppm))
      : (newData = phoneData.sort((a, b) => a.ppm + b.ppm));

    // This only changes after several function calls
    setPhoneData(newData);
  };

  return (
    <div className="centre">
      <div">
        <select onChange={(e) => handleDirectionFilter(e.currentTarget.value)}>
          <option value="">Select one</option>
          <option value="DESC">DESC</option>
          <option value="ASC">ASC</option>
        </select>
        <select onChange={(e) => handleFilterType(e.currentTarget.value)}>
          <option value="">Select one</option>
          <option value="ppm">PPM</option>
          <option value="upfront">upfront</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      {phoneData?.map((phone) => (
        <div key={phone.name}>
          <h3>{phone.name}</h3>
          <p>PPM: {phone.ppm}</p>
          <p>Upfront: {phone.upfront}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
      {filteringBy}
      <br />
      {sortDirection}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `useEffect` in your code, but this is not your only problem.

1. Your `phoneData` depends on both `sortDirection` and `filteringBy`. So you need to use 2 `useEffect`.
2. In this part of your code you've used `ppm` instead of  `upfront` for your properties, you should change it to `upfront`. because you filtered by `upfront`:

   ```
   filteringBy === "upfront" && sortDirection === "ASC"
     ? (newData = phoneData.sort((a, b) => a.ppm - b.ppm))
     : (newData = phoneData.sort((a, b) => a.ppm + b.ppm));
   ```
3. In addition sorting with `+` is not a solution for reverse sorting. You should change second sort to : `sort((a, b) => b.ppm - a.ppm)`.
4. Also you don't need to assign new sorted array to `newData`, Because it sorts in its self.
5. And finally when you're working with array states, its better to make a shallow copy from your state and change the `newData`. It's prevent further unforeseen behaviour in your code:

   ```
   let newData = [...phoneData];
   ```

Here's the code:

```
  const sortPhoneData = () => {
    if (filteringBy && sortDirection) {
      let newData = [...phoneData];
      filteringBy === "ppm" && sortDirection === "ASC"
        ? newData.sort((a, b) => a.ppm - b.ppm)
        : newData.sort((a, b) => b.ppm - a.ppm);

      filteringBy === "upfront" && sortDirection === "ASC"
        ? newData.sort((a, b) => a.upfront - b.upfront)
        : newData.sort((a, b) => b.upfront - a.upfront);
      setPhoneData(newData);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    sortPhoneData();
  }, [filteringBy]);

  useEffect(() => {
    sortPhoneData();
  }, [sortDirection]);
```

[image: Edit condescending-joliot-mldtu]

Comment: Thanks I understand. Can I ask why your'e using 2 useEffects? Would the behaviour not be the same if you just used 1 and had both filteringBy and sortDirection in the dependency array. Like this:   useEffect(() => {
    sortPhoneData();
  }, [filteringBy, sortDirection]);

Comment: @DBG Yes, it's possible. I just wrote with this way for better understanding. :)

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `useEffect` to listen to `filteringBy` because the state [will not reflect immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let newData;
    filteringBy === "ppm" && sortDirection === "ASC"
      ? (newData = phoneData.sort((a, b) => a.ppm - b.ppm))
      : (newData = phoneData.sort((a, b) => a.ppm + b.ppm));

    filteringBy === "upfront" && sortDirection === "ASC"
      ? (newData = phoneData.sort((a, b) => a.ppm - b.ppm))
      : (newData = phoneData.sort((a, b) => a.ppm + b.ppm));

    // This only changes after several function calls
    setPhoneData(newData);
  }, [filteringBy]);  // maybe you have to add phoneData here
```